# Divs arrangement in the page

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I am just getting started with CSS and HTML. I have been trying for quite a long to arange some divs in the page. I am creating a recipes page and I want it to look something like this: each recipe has a title, in the left side an image and the in the right the ingredients and the preparation steps.I also used an XML document and a XSL sheet to display these elements. I am having troubles displaying the right side. I will share with you only the CSS code and the XSL.

CSS :

```
p {
    color: green;
}

.ingredients-header {    
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:120%;
    background-color:#339933;
    position:relative;
    left: 350px;
}

.ingredients {
    position:absolute;
    left: 400px;
}

.preparation-header {
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:120%;
    background-color:#339933;
    position:relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: 350px;
}

.preparation {
    position: relative;
    left: 400px;
}
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict">

<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>Recipe</title>
</head>
<body>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="/recipes/recipe"/>    
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="recipe">
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="./name"/></h2>
    <div class="ingredients-header">
        <h3>Ingredients:</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="ingredients">
        <p><xsl:apply-templates select="./ingredients"/></p>
    </div>
    <div class="preparation-header">
        <h3>Preparation steps:</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="preparation">
        <ol><xsl:apply-templates select="./instructions"/></ol>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ingredients/ingredient">
    <xsl:value-of select="./qty"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="./unit"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="./food"/>
    <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="instructions/instruction">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get an output like this:[image]

Can anyone help me arrange these divs so in order to have the preparation steps under its section?

Comment: Please note that putting `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict"` does not make sense, neither HTML 4 nor HTML5 needs a namespace and if you really wanted to generate XHTML then you would need `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`.

Comment: I replaced the line you mentioned but then all the output was shown on 3 lines, no style was applied..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing .ingredients to position:relative

```
.ingredients {
    position:absolute;
    left: 400px;
}
```

Try removing top: 150px; from .preparation-header too

```
.preparation-header {
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:120%;
    background-color:#339933;
    position:relative;
    left: 350px;
}
```

Comment: It gets a little better but it shows the ingredients and the preparation steps in the Ingredients section. The Preparation steps section does not contain anything.

Comment: I will try to add some extra divs, so that each receipe will have its own div, maybe that will work

Comment: Thank you, this works..I will look closely maybe I will understand how it works. My question is will it work even if I add more recipes to the XML document? Also I need to show an image on the left side of each recipe but I can't find any examples on the internet on how to keep an image in a XML file.
P.S. I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me, about 5 min.

Comment: The rules specified in the css will apply to any matching elements, so if you have multiple recipes using the same layout then they should be formatted the same.

Comment: Out of interest, did you intend for the page to have a horizontal scroll?

Comment: Actually I wanted to create it more fancy, so that each section to have an option to view/hide its elements. But it seems to be pretty complicated..

Comment: Give it a go! (You'll probably need to use Javascript) - you can always ask more questions if you need the help.

Comment: There would be one more thing I want to ask you. Is there a possible way to resize the box (div) that I have created around the Ingredients and Preparation headers? I don't want it to be so long..

Comment: Yes you can set width properties on your elements.  If you don't want your elements to disappear off the side of the screen then you might want to consider using percentage values for "left" and "width" so that they add up to 100.. also consider padding and margins. I've set up a JS Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/90vvyj5c/ so you can try playing around with the values and see the effect. (try setting any "left" property to a percentage e.g. 25% and adding a "width" property of 75%) If you have any more specific questions, you're probably best off starting a new question

Answer (score 0):

```
.ingredients {
    position:absolute;
    left: 400px;
}
```

has position: absolute; while

```
.preparation {
    position: relative;
    left: 400px;
}
```

Has position: relative;.
this may be a large part of your problem.

Hope this helped you a bit

Comment: If I change it to `absolute` it doesn't get any better..I really don't understand how this positioning works.